# What are the infrastructure components in a WCF distributed transaction?

Tags: c#, wcf, msdtc

I am curious about the actual physical location of the components which are responsible for spanning a distributed transaction in a C# application using oracle and SQl server.

specifically, i am looking to know what exactly are these components (eg., is it a CLR dll, windows service, oracle client dll, etc.):

1. Microsoft distributed transaction coordinator (MSDTC)
2. Resource manager
3. or anything else I missed

PS: We are wanting to implement distributed transaction across Oracle and SQLServer databases, and want to make sure the prerequisites are there. eg., if it is a windows service then is it running?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the actual locations, but if your machine is capable of running WCF, then you have everything you need to use distributed transactions.

As far as Windows services are concerned, my understanding is that MSDTC and OracleMTSRecoveryService need to be started.

http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2009/04/07/using-transactionscope-with-odp-net.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Distributed transactions in .NET (enterprise services and `TransactionScope`) and WCF are dependent on MSDTC. WCF can also use WS-AtomicTransaction but that is also handled by MSDTC.